# mongodb - when to start normalizing?

Tags: mongodb

i cant find some real world best practices about when to start normalizing with mongodb.

consider usecase where we have `Entity` and that it can have an arraw of `Items`.
We have 3 genera options:

1. pack all under `Entity` within collection `entities`
2. split in 2 collections: `entities` and `items` where each `Entity` in `entities` jabe collection of references to `items`
3. split again in 2 colections but where each `item` in `items` have reference to `Entity` it belongs to.

   - `Item` can belong only to one `Entity`
   - there are queries to get all `Item`s for given `Entity`

Question:
Are there any tresholds when should we switch from 1 to 2 to 3?

Comment: MongoDB offers some suggestions for when normalisation might be appropriate [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models).

Comment: thats one of the sources i've seen but its still pretty abstract. document noSQL paradigm would suggest pack all into single document but again, question is - till when?